# Selecionar uma imagem entre outras imagens

Tags: php, javascript

Preciso fazer uma "galeria" de imagem e passar algum valor de identificação, em PHP, mostrando qual imagem eu selecionei. A ideia é mostrar varias imagem, como se fossem ícones, e o usuário escolher a preferida. Acho que da para fazer usando `checkbox`, más não sei como faz.

Abaixo um exemplo: Vários ícones, selecionáveis, devidamente identificados...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neste caso você deveria usar *radio* em vez de *checkbox*, porque ao contrário do *checkbox*, o *radio* só lhe permite escolher uma opção.

Crie um `label` para cada imagem e adicione antes da tag `img` um input do tipo *radio*:

```
<label>
   <input type="radio" name="icones" value="valor 1">
   <img src="caminho_da_imagem_1">
</label>
<label>
   <input type="radio" name="icones" value="valor 2">
   <img src="caminho_da_imagem_2">
</label>
```

Note que os *radios* devem possuir o mesmo `name`, o que muda é só o `value` de cada um. É esse `value` que irá identificar qual imagem o usuário escolheu.

**CSS**

No CSS você irá ocultar o *radio* com `opacity`, mas ao clicar na imagem, seu respectivo *radio* será checado mudando a cor da borda da imagem adjacente:

```
/* oculta o radio */
input[name=icones]{
   position: absolute;
   opacity: 0;
}

/* propriedades da imagem */
input[name=icones] + img{
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 4px solid #000;
}

/* altera a cor da borda */    
input[name=icones]:checked + img{
   border-color: #30F519;
}
```

Você pode enviar o valor do *radio* checado via formulário com POST para o PHP e pegar com `$_POST['icones']` (onde `icones` é o `name` dos *radios*).

**Exemplo:** clique em uma imagem e depois clique no botão para exibir o valor de qual *radio* está checado:

```js
function demo(){
   var icones = document.querySelector("input[name=icones]:checked");
   console.log("A imagem selecionada é a: " + icones.value);
}
```

```css
input[name=icones]{
   position: absolute;
   opacity: 0;
}

input[name=icones] + img{
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 4px solid #000;
}

input[name=icones]:checked + img{
   border-color: #30F519;
}
```

```html
Selecione uma imagem:
<form method="post" action="pagina.php">
   <div style="display: flex;">
      <div>
         <label>
            <input type="radio" name="icones" value="1">
            <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ultraviolet/2x/avatar.png">
         </label>
      </div>
      <div>
         <label>
            <input type="radio" name="icones" value="2">
            <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ultraviolet/2x/avatar.png">
         </label>
      </div>
      <div>
         <label>
            <input type="radio" name="icones" value="3">
            <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ultraviolet/2x/avatar.png">
         </label>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
<button onclick="demo()">Value da imagem selecionada</button>
```

Comment: Perfeito! Era isso mesmo, muito obrigado!!!